# D3 v4 Pie Chart Update empty `d` attributes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to rewrite the classic [Pie Chart Update, V](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5682158) example using latest D3 v4. Unfortunately the paths' `d` attributes aren't calculated.

Here is my [gist](https://gist.github.com/zemirco/5fd7524237cfe69a4d78383dfd8949e7/) and the [block](https://bl.ocks.org/zemirco/5fd7524237cfe69a4d78383dfd8949e7/77c4b1273b6c14d69d3d98711b4ec0962b3a4c1d). So far I've only changed

- `d3.scale.category20()` -> `d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20)`
- `d3.layout.pie()` -> `d3.pie()`
- `d3.svg.arc()` -> `d3.arc()`

As you can see in the DOM the paths are there but they do not have any `d` attributes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like something to do with how `path = path.data(data1, key);` works. In v3 this would initially return three `path` items in an array, but in v4 you get something quite different (`zi {_groups: Array[1], _parents: Array[1], _enter: Array[1], _exit: Array[1]}`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a few issues, especially not setting the d attribute on enter.

Here's a gist showing the change https://bl.ocks.org/tezzutezzu/c2653d42ffb4ecc01ffe2d6c97b2ee5e

<s>In my code there is still a bug in calculating the adjacent arcs on change, but this should resolve your initial problem.</s>

The exit animation is now also working. I had to make sure that objects were copied before the interpolation.

edit: grammar

Comment: Have you seen the original example? They don't set the `d` attribute specifically.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is due to the changes in how selection work in v4. See this slide for the differences: https://iros.github.io/d3-v4-whats-new/#20

Comment: Here is my latest update with your improvements - https://bl.ocks.org/zemirco/5fd7524237cfe69a4d78383dfd8949e7/aea2d09c9d10e1cba9581844956a9ffd202ac4b0. As you can see the `enter` transition is pretty nice. The `exit` transition moves the circles back to 12 o'clock which is not right.

Comment: start and end angles are both set to the end angle of the last arc.

Maybe there is a problem in the findNeighborArc function?

Comment: Sure. 

For the exit transition of an arc I still need to know which is its neighbour. 

For this reason, I make a copy of its neighbour arc in another object: "_previous" as the object "_current" changes during the enter animation.